# Finding and replacing keywords with link using DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I've been researching a way to find certain keywords if they are inside of a 'p', 'span' or 'blockquote' and replace them with a link, using DOMDocument. I've written a piece of Regex which achieves this, but I would much rather use DOMDocument as it should result in a better solution.

The code below has two main issues, if I place `&amp;` in $html .. it crashes because `&amp;` isn't escaped and I can't find a way to correctly escape `&amp;`.

A smaller issue, not so important .. but if the HTML is invalid DOMDocument tries to correct the HTML and I seem unable to prevent this.

The preg_replace uses an array, because eventually this will be dynamically loaded using multiple keywords.

```
$html = '
<blockquote>Random we random text</blockquote>
<p>We like to match text</p>
<p>This is sample text</p>';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->strictErrorChecking = false;

$dom->loadHtml(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"));

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query('//text()[not(ancestor::a)][(ancestor::p|ancestor::blockquote)]') as $node)
{
    $replaced = preg_replace(
        array('/(^|\s)'.preg_quote('we', '/').'(\s|$)/msi'), 
        array('<a href="#wrapped">we</a>'),
        $node->wholeText
    );
    $newNode  = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
    $newNode->appendXML($replaced);
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $node);
}

$result = mb_substr($dom->saveXML($xpath->query('//body')->item(0)), 6, -7, "UTF-8");

libxml_clear_errors();

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with ampersand is coming from the fact that you inject HTML with `appendXML($replaced)` but do not escape `<`, `>` nor `&` of the text parts.

The main issue is that even though you use DOMDocument to avoid RegEx manipulation, you still manipulate HTML that way on a smaller scale and thus bump into similar problems.

Here is a way to avoid all that. I did not maintain the *array* style of replace to not make it over-complicated. I am sure you will manage to extend this with other types of replacements when needed:

```
foreach ($xpath->query(
        '//text()[not(ancestor::a)][(ancestor::p|ancestor::blockquote)]')
        as $node) {
    // Keep a reference to the parent node:
    $parent = $node->parentNode;
    // Split text (e.g. "random we random text") into parts so we 
    // can isolate the parts that must be modified.
    // e.g. into: ["random ", "we", " random text"] 
    $parts = preg_split('/\b('.preg_quote('we', '/').')\b/msi',
                          $node->textContent, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    foreach ($parts as $index => $part) {
        if (empty($part)) continue;
        // Parts corresponding with the captured expression in the 
        // split delimiter (e.g. "we") occur at odd indexes:
        if ($index % 2) {
            // Create the anchor the DOM-way. The value that is passed
            // should be not be interpreted as HTML, so we escape it:
            $el = $dom->createElement('a', htmlentities($part));
            $el->setAttribute('href', '#wrapped');
        } else {
            // Create the text node the DOM-way. The text will be escaped
            // by the library, as it knows it should not be interpreted 
            // as HTML:
            $el = $dom->createTextNode($part);
        }
        // insert this part, before the node we are processing
        $parent->insertBefore($el, $node);
    }
    // when all parts are inserted, delete the node we split
    $parent->removeChild($node);
}
```

This way you'll not have the ampersand problem.

NB: There is no way I know of you can prevent DOMDocument to "fix" invalid HTML.